# Class variables vs class level instance variables

Tags: ruby

Consider this code:

```
class Polygon
  @sides=1
  @@sides = 10
  class << self; attr_accessor :sides end
  def self.sides
    @@sides
  end
end
```

If I print `sides`:

```
p Polygon.sides
```

I get `10`. If I change the order of `class` and `self.sides`, I will get `1`. What is the cause of this behaviour? How can I call the `@@sides` or `@sides` independently of the order of the methods?

**edit**

I found this excellent [post](http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/45-more-classes/lessons/113-class-variables) that discuss the difference between class variables, class instance variables and instance variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class << self; attr_accessor :sides end
```

is equivalent to:

```
def self.sides
  @sides
end

def self.sides=(arg)
  @sides = arg
end
```

This `sides`method then gets overwritten.
Use two methods (with different names) to access both variables (or put them in an array and return that in a method).